# Posterior entropy behaviour for Poisson model

Tags: probability, bayesian, entropy, poisson-distribution

Suppose $Y \sim Poisson(k \theta)$ is observed (number of events),
where $k>0$ is a constant (length of observation time)
and $\theta$ is an unknown parameter (event rate) with some prior distribution.

Is it possible to show that the expectation (with respect to $Y$ and $\theta$) of the Shannon entropy of the posterior is convex in $k$? i.e. the expected information gain is subject to decreasing returns in the length of observation time.

I'm interested in results for any particular choice of prior (except a point mass) or for all priors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Information theory representation

The expectation with respect to $Y$ of the posterior entropy is the [conditional entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy)
$$
H(\theta | Y) = H(\theta) - \mathrm{I}(Y; \theta)
$$
where $H(\theta)$ is prior entropy and $I$ is [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information).

Let $g(k)$ denote the mutual information as a function of $k$.
So the question can be rephrased as showing that $g$ is concave.

### Submodularity of mutual information (discrete case)

The proof extends a similar result on mutual information under repeated observations.

Let $\mathcal{S} = \{ Z_1, Z_2,\ldots, Z_n \}$, a set of conditionally independent (given $\theta$) random variables with the same distribution.
Define $f(\mathcal{A}) = \mathrm{I}(\mathcal{A}; \theta)$ where $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{S}$.

Proposition 2 of [Krause and Guestrin](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.1394) shows that
$f(A)$ is a [submodular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submodular_set_function) function (the proof follows from submodularity of entropy).

(Edit: in fact a modification of this proposition is needed to deal with the fact that $\theta$ is a continuous parameter. See the proof of equation (25) in Appendix G of [Prangle, Harbisher and Gillespie](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.05703v3).)

That is, for every $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{S}$ and $Z_i \in \mathcal{S} \setminus \mathcal{B}$:
$$f(\mathcal{A} \cup \{ Z_i \}) - f(\mathcal{A}) \geq f(\mathcal{B} \cup \{ Z_i \}) - f(\mathcal{B})$$
i.e. the marginal gain in mutual information by observing $Z_i$ is larger when the set of existing observations is smaller.

### Main proof

Let $h = k/N$ where $N \in \mathbb{N}$.
Define $Z_i \sim Poisson(h \theta)$ (conditionally independent given $\theta$).
Let $Y_k = \sum_{i=1}^{N} Z_i$,
$Y_{k+h} = \sum_{i=1}^{N+1} Z_i$,
$Y_{k+2h} = \sum_{i=1}^{N+2} Z_i$.
Then $Y_k \sim Poisson(k \theta)$,
$Y_{k+1} \sim Poisson(k \theta + h)$,
$Y_{k+2} \sim Poisson(k \theta + 2h)$.

The submodularity result above gives

$$g(k \theta + h) - g(k \theta) \geq g(k \theta + 2h) - g(k \theta + h),$$

which rearranges to

$$\frac{g(k \theta + 2h) - 2g(k \theta + h) + g(k \theta)}{h^2} \leq 0.$$

Taking the limit $N \to 0$ gives that $g''(k) \leq 0$ and thus $g$ is concave.

#### Extension

The proof just relies on an [infinite divisibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_(probability)) property of the Poisson distribution, so the result will be true for other observation distributions also satisfying this.

#### Credit

Thanks to Iain Murray for helpful suggestions on relevant approaches for this proof.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer based on the original question**.

The Shannon entropy of the Poisson distribution is

$$\lambda [1-\log(\lambda )]+e^{-\lambda }\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {\lambda ^{k}\log(k!)}{k!}},$$
where $\lambda = \theta k$ in your case. For each value of $\theta$, this seems to be a concave function of $k$:

```
# Approximation to the Shannon Entropy truncating the series at N
shan.pois <- Vectorize(function(k){
  x <- 1:N
  val <- (theta*k)*(1-log(theta*k)) + sum(  dpois(x, lambda = theta*k)*lgamma(x+1) )
  return(val)
  })

# Plot for different values of theta
N <- 1000

theta <- 1
curve(shan.pois,0,10, n = 1000, ylim = c(0,5),lwd=2, xlab = "k", ylab = "S(k)")

thetas <- seq(0.1,10,by = 0.1)
for(i in 1:length(thetas)){
  theta <- thetas[i]
  curve(shan.pois,0,10, n = 1000, add = T, col = "grey")
}
```

So, even if you find a strongly informative prior that, for a specific sample, the posterior expectation is convex, it will eventually become concave by the concentration properties of the posterior distribution.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unless I'm missing a connection, I think you're looking at *expectation of the entropy of y wrt the posterior distribution*, but I'm interested in *expectation of the entropy of the posterior distribution with respect to y and $\theta$*. I'll reword the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @DennisPrangle That is certainly a very different question! I will have a go.